# CSS - on hover affect full width of element, without removing padding

Tags: html, css

I have a series of nested `ul` and `li` elements, to create a sidebar nav system. When the user hovers over one of the `li` elements I want the entire width of the background to change (shown right), not just the inside of the container (shown left).

[image: Different hover styles]

The problem I'm having is that in order to make the entire width change, I need to remove the `ul` `padding-left` which then removes the indentation and 'nested' look of the list elements.

An example below shows the behaviour currently present, where the `background-color` does not change for the entire width. Preferably I wouldn't have to manually add in indentation for each element, as the nested padding works quite nicely as is, but am open to suggestions :D

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Work</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Piece 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Piece 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
```

**My questions**:

1. How can I make the background of the entire width of the `li` update on hover, without removing the indentation for the nested list items.
2. Why are the `width: 100%` `li` elements not overflowing outside the nav bar? Since I thought `width: 100%` meant their width was the same as their parent's widths, which surely as they are indented would mean they would extend beyond.

Thanks!

***Post Answer Edit***
*The accepted answer is definitely good, but the solution i ended up with was dynamically generating the navbar elements with JavaScript according to an object.*

Comment: Your HTML is invalid -- `<ul>` can have `<li>` children only.

Comment: @Kosh so should the netsed `ul`  be inside another `li` tag in that case?

Comment: Correct, nested `ul` should be in `li`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution works for any number of nested levels.

The trick is using [`CSS counter`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp) to pad levels.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


li {
  counter-increment: section;
  counter-reset: section;
}

a:before {
  content: counters(section, '');
  opacity: 0
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Work</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Piece 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Piece 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Piece 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Piece 2.2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the links to be the width of the list, you can remove the padding of the unordered list (ul). Put the padding on the links instead:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

ul ul li a{
  padding-left: 25px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Work</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Piece 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Piece 2</a></li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
```

Comment: So, the only option would be to manually add padding to each new indentation level?

Comment: Well, if you don't have too many list levels, this can be a solution.

Comment: Brilliant! So would you be able to explain the second part of my question? Since I'm confused about the behaviour.

Comment: With the padding, the sizing of the element changes, padding means that you increase the indent in an element so the children of the element cannot have a 100% width

Comment: Your HTML is invalid -- `<ul>` can have `<li>` children only.